# Why do I have to use a 1:1 ethanol:water solution to hydrolyse aspirin?

Tags: hydrolysis

I understand that water itself would not work as aspirin is not very soluble in water but Why not just use 100% ethanol?

Comment: Because you can't **hydro**lyze something without water.

Answer (score 1):

Hydrolysis means to break something apart (e.g. chemical bonds) with water.

[image: Aspirin hydrolysis]

If there's no water, there's no hydrolysis.

Comment: Also the ethanol is needed to solubilise the aspirin which is not very soluble in water.